# Temporarily use integers with QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: qt, combobox, qspinbox

Suppose I have a whole group of spinboxes, comboboxes, and whatnot, where I can set all sorts of variables for an application; a control panel, if you will. One of them is a `QDoubleSpinBox *dec` and, normally, I use it as it should be, with decimals, but there is a certain combo box that dynamically enables/disables some spinboxes and comboboxes, depending on the selected entry. One such change makes use of the `dec` spinbox, which, for that time only, needs to be limited to integer values and increments.

For example, if `dec` normally has the range `0.00..99.99` and the increment is `0.1`, when I select that certain entry in the controlling combo box, I need `dec` to be on the same range (`99` is just fine), but emitting only integers, and being able to be changed with integer steps, only (i.e. range is `0..99`, step size `1`).

While I discovered (beginner in Qt) that I could simply force `setDecimals()` and `setSingleStep()` for that particular entry in the combobox, it turns out I have to use them for all, to be able to revert the changes, which can add to the code. Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: If your spin box suddenly doesn't allow for doubles anymore, I would say it is conceptionally different and should be replaced by a normal spin box for integers.
If you need you can just have both spin boxes coexisting and then `hide()` and `show()` them when needed.

Comment: That's not a bad solution, actually, even if it would still require calling `hide()` and `show()` for all the other combo entries, to revert (just like `setDecimals()` and `setSingleStep()`). Add this as an answer, if noone will come with anything else, this is a better implementation, compared to my ugly hack.

Comment: Your solution with `setDecimals` and `setSingleStep` is simple and to the point. The alternative is to stack multiple widgets and synchronize their values: that's way more work.

Answer (score 0):

If your spin box suddenly doesn't allow for doubles anymore, I would say it is conceptually different and should be replaced by a normal `QSpinBox` for integers.

You can just have both spin boxes coexisting and then `hide()` and `show()` them when needed. 
This also avoids continuously casting between `int`'s and `double`'s.

Comment: While I still consider this a viable alternative, as @KubaOber pointed out (and as I found out, myself), is that the synchronizing between the two also takes an extra effort, so I simply made a conditional which makes it use the `setDecimals()` and `setSingleStep()` appropiately, when that particular combo entry is chosen.